# Scrolltop function not working correctly when scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button that scrolls to another element. This works fine on desktop but on mobile if I scroll a little bit and click the button, the function does not scroll precisely to the element I want but is a bit off, even though I didn't specify any offset.

On desktop I have a fixed menu that changes size, so that is why in below code I check for desktop or mobile using the window width:

```
if(window.outerWidth > 991) {
    console.log('desktop');
    $("body").on("click","#bestellenbtn",function(){
        var scrollmenuheight = $('.scrollmenu').height();
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bestellen").offset().top - scrollmenuheight
    }, 1000);
    });
}else{
    console.log('mobile');
    $("body").on("click","#bestellenbtn",function(){
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bestellen").offset().top
    }, 1000);
    });
}
```

This is the button that starts the function:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="bestellenbtn"><button class="btnstyle blue-inverse" type="button" name="button">Bestellen</button></a>
```

And the element:

```
<div class="separator" id="bestellen">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Bestellen</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added a copy of the page in a codepen so you can see it for yourself (click the first of 4 blue buttons on mobile view):

https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/RwGmaMQ You can resize to get the mobile version.

What can I do?

I've tried changing the offset but that shouldn't be necessary because on mobile there is no fixed menu that changes the height of the document.

I made a short video to show what the problem is:

https://gyazo.com/431163072afb0de9a6488ebfba895ff5

Comment: Looks like your code never goes to the else part. What happens when you remove the else part and initialize the scrollmenuheight with 0 in the click function and and put the "if" below that line to get the scrollmenu height when outerWidth is > 991?

Comment: Why do you animate both `documentElement` and `body`? I think that may be causing issues.

Comment: @fuchs777 I tried it but on mobile it still does not scroll precisely on the element if you scrolled a littlebit, only at the very top of the page. Also I think it does go to the else part because I see the console log test appear.

Comment: @twan For me the console log shows desktop. You could add console.log('window.outerWidth:'+window.outerWidth); inside to see what gets evaluated when the script runs.

Comment: @fuchs777 Then I get: window.outerWidth:375. Are you looking on the mobile version? I use inspect element and then go to devices, select a size (like iphone X or something) and refresh.

Comment: @twan adding a +1 seems to fix it, could be a rounding error or another script on your page interfering with scrolling. scrollTop: ($("#bestellen").offset().top + 1)

Comment: @fuchs777 I still have it with + 1. I added a video to my original post to show what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `if-statement` inside the function that handels `#bestellenbtn` click.
2. Use `window.innerWidth` instead of `window.outerWidth`. However, For compatibility reason,  it is better that you use the following code instead.

`var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);` .

3. On mobile, use `Element.scrollIntoView()` with smooth behaviour. Let JS rules.

#### Element.scrollIntoView()

> The Element interface's scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element's
> parent container such that the element on which scrollIntoView() is
> called is visible to the user. [MDN - Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
document.querySelector("#bestellen")
          .scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"})
```

---

```
$("body").on("click","#bestellenbtn",function(){
var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  if(viewportWidth > 991) {
    console.log('desktop');
    var scrollmenuheight = $('.scrollmenu').height();
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#bestellen").offset().top - scrollmenuheight
    }, 1000);
  }else{
    console.log('mobiel');
    document.querySelector("#bestellen")
      .scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"})
  }
});
```

#### Update.

> Do you have an idea why on desktop when I click, the animation is not
> instant but only starts after about 1 second? Maybe the function is
> too heavy?
>
> That is probably because of animation duration. Try using 300 or 700 as timeout for the animate function.

---

If you need a similar behaviour as on mobile, use `window.scrollTo` with smooth behaviour.

> `Window.scrollTo()` scrolls to a particular set of coordinates in the
> document. - [MDN - Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```
$("body").on("click","#bestellenbtn",function(){
  var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  if(viewportWidth > 991) {
    console.log('desktop');
    var scrollmenuheight = $('.scrollmenu').height();
    var offsetTop = $("#bestellen").offset().top - scrollmenuheight;
    window.scrollTo({
      top: offsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    
  
  }else{
    console.log('mobiel');
    document.querySelector("#bestellen")
      .scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"})
  }
});
```

---

*On mobile, it scroll faster because the distance between `#bestellenbtn`  and `#bestellen` is more than the distance between those two elements on desktop.*

Comment: Do you have an idea why on desktop when I click, the animation is not instant but only starts after about 1 second? Maybe the function is too heavy?

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't change anything. I don't mean the animation speed but when I click the button, nothing happens for 1 second and then it starts animating

Comment: @twan I do not notice 1 second delay. Do you really spend [waste] your time fixing 1s delay?

Comment: What do you mean waste? If you click a button and it takes 1-2 seconds for something to happen users will think its broken, ofcourse I try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I have understood is you want to scroll down to a particular section of your page on clicking an item in the menu. This can very easily be done with HTML. In your `href` of the link element replace `javascript:void(0);` with the id of the element where you want to scroll to i.e. `#bestellen`. Check my pen [here](https://codepen.io/alim1496/pen/abmgLjv). Once you click **One**, **Two**, **Three** or **Four** then you will be scrolled to that particular section.

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know about this but I want the animation

Comment: I have added the `scroll-behavior: smooth` property. It works fine. Please have a look.

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim Thank you but I need a little offset, because I have a sticky menu. With your code my sticky menu covers the element.